Tableau Calculated Field whether measure or dimension
You're tasked with analyzing sales data in Tableau. A calculated field is created with the logic if sum(Sales) > 100 then ‘A’ else ‘B’ end, resulting in a data type of string. Given this scenario, would the calculated field be categorized as a dimension or measure by default? Explain your reasoning.
What will be the calculated  field dimension or measure in this secanrio

Why don't you just create a calculated field in Tableau and find out?  Tableau Public is free.

Fields are not permanently assigned a role as a dimension or a measure. A field, think column in a table, can be used as dimension in some contexts and a dimension in others. The role shown in the date pane on the left is merely the default role, and can be changed on a view.
When people say that "X is a dimension" (or a measure), that is a form of shorthand. A more wordy but accurate phrase would be something like "field X is being used as a dimension in the current view" or perhaps "Field X takes on the role of a dimension by default, unless changed into a measure for specific views".
Dimension or Measure as a role is not a permanent attribute of a field, unlike say its name or datatype.
Dimensions are used to segment or partition data rows in the data source table, and typically follow the keyword GROUP BY in the generated SQL. In your natural language description of your viz, dimensions would often follow words like "for each" or "by". Measures are fields that will be aggregated or summarized, and thus require you to select an aggregation function like SUM(), MAX() or COUNT() when you use them.
Data rows that share the same dimension values are grouped together, and then the data source creates one summary row describing each group of data rows, summarizing each field treated as a measure according to the selected aggregation function.
A field can play different roles at different times. A good example would be a Date field. You can sometimes treat Year(Date) as a dimension to report sales for each year. Or you could treat Max(Date) as a measure to, say, report the date of the latest sale for each Product. Date is still the same field, just used differently to answer different questions.
Also, the concept of dimensions and measures only applies to aggregate queries. If you turn off aggregation from the Analysis menu, then you are just back to plain old fields - that's why the SUM() prefixes will disappear in that case.
The Tableau documentation is quite good in places, but it really does a poor job explaining this basic concept. The section that drives me crazy is titled "Aggregating Dimensions" where the title alone contradicts itself.
To finally sort-of answer your question, the default role depends in part on the data type for your field. So if you create a string valued calculated field, then Tableau will treat that field as a dimension by default. You can change the default to a measure, but will have to choose the aggregation function to apply such as COUNT() or MAX(). Bonus points if you know what MAX() means for string fields.

To whoever has marked down this answer, please at least explain your complaint in a comment. It seems to me it directly responds to the poster's request to "would the calculated field be categorized as a dimension or measure by default? Explain your reasoning." - and the information in the answer is accurate. So what's the complaint?
